# Why is this code not taking input for "Designation"?

Tags: c++, class, gcc

[image: why is this not taking inputs for "Designation"?]

As you can see from the screenshot, the `fgets()` function is running only once to take in the string `name`, but it is not accepting the `designation` string and is skipping onto the "salary" input. What is intriguing me even more is the fact that this same code is running perfectly well in TurboC3....I am getting problems only with GCC compiler based IDE such as DevCPP and now in GCC itself in Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class emp
{
private:
    char name[20], desig[20];
    int id;
    float salary;

public:
    void getdata()
    {
        cout << "ENTER NAME:\n";
        fgets(name, 20, stdin);
        cout << "ENTER ID:\n";
        cin >> id;
        cout << "ENTER DESIGNATION:\n";
        fgets(desig, 20, stdin);
        cout << "ENTER SALARY:\n";
        cin >> salary;
    }

    void showdata()
    {
        cout << "NAME:- " << name << "\n";
        cout << "ID:- " << id << "\n";
        cout << "DESIGNATION: " << desig << "\n";
        cout << "SALARY: " << salary << "\n";
    }
};

int main()

{

    emp ins[3];
    int i;
    cout << "ENTER DETAILS:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        ins[i].getdata();
    cout << "*****************************DETAILS***************************\n";

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        ins[i].showdata();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question by converting the title to lower case. Generally speaking, writing in all caps will be perceived by native English speakers as shouting loudly, which is perceived poorly. Hopefully this edit attracts more helpful feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading from standard input, do not mix C library functions, such as `fgets()`, and C++ `std::cin` operators. The C library knows nothing about what the C++ library is doing.

Change your code to use only `stdin`, or only `std::cin`, to read standard input.

Answer (score 0):

***Don't Mix C and C++ Input Streams***

Either use `stdin` or `istream`. In terms, this means to not use both `fgets()` and `cin` in the same area. Use one or the other. To read a complete string, with whitespace, use [`std::getline(std::cin, input)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: thanks...it worked........learned something new.....and also learned that TurboC3 should not be used for learning C++ as it mixes C and C++

Answer (score 0):

thanx guys....ur hints helped...however...I did some more research and found out that I could use getline without string types strings....(i.e strings made out of character array) by using cin.getline(string_name,string_size).....iz more convenient this coz this wud allow me to use all the conventional string functions without problems.....thanx again....